# emails not working after domain has been forwarded to new hosting?

Tags: domain, forwarding, mx-record

What's the best course of action after the forwarding of domain has been done and apparently the email has been forgotten to be taken into account?

I just forwarded the domain to a new server hosting and i forgot to take into account the emails from the old provider? A few concerns arise:

1. the emails won't be lost, right?
2. will pointing the MX records to the old mail server IP address fix this issue right away?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what gekkz mentioned. Old emails if any will remain with your old provider unless and until you have closed account with them. So just pointing your MX record to the old server will start delivering your mails there( I dont think this is not what you want, from your question. You want to access the old emails). I am not sure how your users will access the old mails since now all the domain names might be pointing to your new service provider. One method is, you can try configuring the POP3 or IMAP settings to point to the old IP address(of the earlier provider) and see if you download all your old emails to your email client. Once you download all ofthem just change the settings to how it was earlier. All your problems would be sorted out if this works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Any e-mail sent to a domain with no MX records configured will not be delivered.
2. If your old host is still hosting the e-mail for you, then this will do the trick.